# Let's Encrypt Certs Fail "openssl verify" Verification

Tags: ssl, certificates, letsencrypt

I've followed the guidance from other Stack answers- there's a gazillion related to this- in building my `openssl verify` command to validate my Let's Encrypt certs, shown below:

```
openssl verify -show_chain /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem
```

But it fails with the error:

```
CN = mail.example.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem: verification failed
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem: OK
Chain:
depth=0: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3 (untrusted)
depth=1: C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
```

Even if I substitute `fullchain.pem` for `chain.pem` this nonetheless fails. But these are all the certs Let's Encrypt distributed to me!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710447/how-can-i-remove-the-last-certificate-from-a-pem-file-that-contains-three/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> openssl verify -show_chain /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem
> ```

This command is wrong. It will try to verify all the given certificates independently from each other, i.e. not build a trust chain and verify the first. Instead the command should have been:

```
openssl verify -untrusted chain.pem cert.pem
```

With `-untrusted` the intermediate certificate will be given. The root certificate ISRG X1 will be taken from the trust store in modern systems, otherwise it should be given with `-trusted` or `-CAfile`.

Answer (score -1):

## Updated Answer:

I'm marking @SteffenUllich 's answer as the correct one, but I'll just expand on parts of it in relation to what's inside the bundles and the Trust Store he references in his answer.

## Files Let's Encrypt Gives You:

The error *appeared* to indicate that I had a broken Chain of Trust and was missing *at least* one cert. But I couldn't know what I was missing until I understood what certs that I had.

So I reviewed the files Let's Encrypt gave me which live in the path `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/` and found the bundles were comprised of:

**cert.pem**:       The server's cert
**chain.pem**:      Let's Encrypt's "***R3***" cert + "***ISRG Root X1***" ("Intermediate Cert")
**fullchain.pem**:  "chain.pem" + "cert.pem"
**privkey.pem**:    Your Private key. The Public key is encoded into `cert.pem`

NOTE: [To validate the above using a one-liner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696244/334294), replace `mail.example.com` with your own cert name in the path:

```
while openssl x509 -noout -text; do :; done < /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem

while openssl x509 -noout -text; do :; done < /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem 

while openssl x509 -noout -text; do :; done < /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem
```

## Trust Store:

It appeared that my initial attempt to validate the server cert lacked a "Trust Anchor" enabling the chain to be traced back to the origin.

**HOWEVER**: If the `-CAfile` is not specified, as Steffen notes `openssl` will parse the "Trust Store" to find a root cert to complete the Chain of Trust.

To install a "Trust Store", search for package "ca-certificates" / "ca-certificates-bundle" in your distro.

So since the CA certs are already there, nothing additional need be downloaded for the chain to be traced successfully as I erroneously stated in my original answer. Indeed, the verification is more likely to succeed if you leave `openssl` to just parse everything in the Trust Store until it finds something that matches.

To find the location of your "Trust Store":

```
openssl version -d
```

In Alpine Linux, this is `/etc/ssl`

## Conclusion:

Thanks to Steffen for bringing to my attention that the command I issued succeeded for the wrong reason ;-).  And `openssl` documentation could be a bit better to be fair...

Comment: The explanation is wrong. `DST Root CA X3` is obsolete, instead `ISRG X1` is used as root directly. The signing by `DST Root CA X3` is only for compatibility with older systems, i.e. it is cross-signed with the previous root. The claimed fix with "isrg-root-ocsp-x1.pem" is not a fix at all, this certificate is useless here. The actual fix in your line was adding chain.pem with `-untrusted`, which you did not do in your original test.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for your feedback! I'd have been unaware my command succeeded for all the wrong reasons if you hadn't have clocked it; thanks bud-